# How to use interstitial ad with webview Back press?

Tags: java, android, admob

Problem is if InterstitialAd show it's work as expected
like : backpress -> ad show -> webview go back
but if ad not show whole app close , webview not go back .

**My Code :**

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (webview.canGoBack()) {
                    webview.goBack();
                    mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
                    Log.d("---AdMob", "show");
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the Interstitial Callbacks first.
In the AdDismissed callback navigate the webview by checking:
`if (webview.canGoBack()) webview.goBack();`

Then follow the backpress like this:
BackPress > Check if Interstitial Loaded
if loaded, show the Ad (webview navigation will be handled when the ad is closed)
if not loaded, navigate webview to previous page.